# how to make matblazor RTL (right to left)

Tags: blazor, matblazor

I'm new to **Blazor** and recently I'm learning it.

Does anyone knows how to make **Matblazor** components **Right To Left** ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add `dir=rtl` to the `body` or a element that you want to create this effect (if you add this in a `div`, it will only apply to the elements inside that `div`).

Working example:

```
<body dir="rtl">
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MatBlazor/dist/matBlazor.js"></script>
</body>
```

Pictures:

[image: Add RTL direction to page]

[image: The result]

Comment: Thank you Dear @mhdcindioglu you were right It works. I did not understand what you meant correctly. and wrongly I used __style="direction:rtl"__ instead of __dir="rtl"__ Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

Just add dir attribute to body in you index.html and set its value to rtl